# How to use timer callback in ROS?

Tags: ros, rospy, ros-kinetic, callbacks

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working with ROS Kinetic. Like in ROS2, we can use a `create_timer()` function as described [here](https://github.com/ros2/demos/blob/master/demo_nodes_py/demo_nodes_py/topics/talker.py#L28).

Similarly I would want to use a similar functionality in rospy in ROS. Something that is mentioned [here](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Time) in point 3.

Can anyone give an example how to use it ?

I am trying something like this in my class constructor but it never enters the callback function :

```
class DemoNode():
    def __init__(self):
        print("entering constructor")
        #super().__init__('custom_talker')
        self.pub = rospy.Publisher('topic',customMessage, queue_size=10)
        self.counter = 1
        print("creating a publisher")
        self.timer = rospy.Timer(rospy.Duration(1), self.demo_callback)
        print("timer called")

    def demo_callback(self):
        print("entering callback")
        msg = DetectedObject()
        print("Reading the message correctly")
        msg.id = self.counter
        counter += 1
        rospy.loginfo("Publishing message {}".format(msg.id))
        pub.publish(msg)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    print("entering main")
    rospy.init_node('custom_talker')
    try:
        DemoNode()
        print("entering Try")
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        print("exception thrown")
        pass
```

Is it correct ? The node is running but it `never enters the callback function`

Also, it is mentioned that this Timer is supported in ROS 1.5+ . What is exactly that ? Does Kinetic already fulfill this condition ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/304085/how-to-use-timer-callback-in-ros?/) by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 667 on 2018-09-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
class DemoNode():
  def __init__(self):
    print("entering constructor")
    #super().__init__('custom_talker')
    self.pub = rospy.Publisher('topic',customMessage, queue_size=10)
    self.counter = 1
    print("creating a publisher")
    self.timer = rospy.Timer(rospy.Duration(1), self.demo_callback)
    print("timer called")

  def demo_callback(self, timer):
    print("entering callback")
    msg = DetectedObject()
    print("Reading the message correctly")
    msg.id = self.counter
    self.counter += 1
    rospy.loginfo("Publishing message {}".format(msg.id))
    self.pub.publish(msg)

if __name__ == '__main__':

  print("entering main")
  rospy.init_node('custom_talker')
  try:
    DemoNode()
    print("entering Try")
    rospy.spin()
  except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
    print("exception thrown")
    pass
```

This should work, you were missing `rospy.spin()` that was main issue, and alos `timer` in callback, as it needs 2 arguments(including self). Also `self` was missing at 2 places in demo_callback.

---

Originally posted by [Choco93](https://answers.ros.org/users/31829/choco93/) with karma: 685 on 2018-09-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on 2018-09-24**:
worked like a charm. Thankyou :)

**Comment by [Choco93](https://answers.ros.org/users/31829/choco93/) on 2018-09-24**:
Glad I could be of help :)

**Comment by [nihalsoans91](https://answers.ros.org/users/37719/nihalsoans91/) on 2020-05-11**:
This helps, Thank you